# Java replaceAll method with a variable string and escaped dot

Tags: java, string, variables, escaping, replaceall

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out, so I ask for your help. Here's the deal:

```
String str = "02-EST-WHATEVER-099-00.dwg";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("([^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-)[^-_\\.]+(\\.[^-_\\.]+)", "$1$2");
```

The block of code above results in `02-EST-WHATEVER-099-.dwg` (removed the last "00", just before the extension). **Great, that's what I need!**

But the RegEx I use above has to be created on the fly (the field I'm removing can be in a different position). So I used some code to create the RegEx string (here's what the result would look like if I just declared it):

```
String regexRemoveRev = "([^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-)[^-_\\.]+(\\.[^-_\\.]+)";
```

Now, if I `out.print(regexRemoveRev)`, I get `([^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-)[^-_\.]+(\.[^-_\.]+)` (notice the single backslashes).

And when i try the `replaceAll` again, it doesn't work:

```
String str = "02-EST-WHATEVER-099-00.dwg";
String newStr = str.replaceAll(regexRemoveRev, "$1$2");
```

So I thought it could be because of the single backslashes, and I tried declaring regexRemoveRev with 4 of them, instead of just 2:

```
String regexRemoveRev = "([^-_\\\\.]+-[^-_\\\\.]+-[^-_\\\\.]+-[^-_\\\\.]+-)[^-_\\\\.]+(\\\\.[^-_\\\\.]+)";
```

The output of `out.print(regexRemoveRev)` is the double backslash version of the RegEx, as expected:

```
([^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-)[^-_\\.]+(\\.[^-_\\.]+)
```

But the replace still doesn't work!

How do I get this to do what I want?

Comment: Geez, does anybody understand this question? Please be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve! By the way, wouldn't you be better off with a "split-modify array of Strings-rejoin" style of operation in this case?

Comment: it works and removes last two digits, check your code

Comment: @ppeterka That really doesn't help. What did you not understand? The dashes (`-`) in the string can also be dots (`.`) or underscores (`_`), so splitting arrays would be rather harder, I believe.

@hoaz Which version worked for you? None worked for me.

Comment: "Now, if I out.print(regexRemoveRev), I get `([^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-[^-_\.]+-)[^-_\.]+(\.[^-_\.]+)` (notice the single backslashes)." - that is correct, a double backslash in a string literal produces a single backslash in the resulting `String`.  But note that inside `[]` expressions you don't need to backslash-escape the dot at all because special characters aren't special in character classes.

Comment: @hoaz Ok. I see what I did wrong. Your input was helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: @IanRoberts That's right. Thank you very much as well!

Comment: Have to agree with @ppeterka on the split, modify, join approach. String.split will take a regex, so I think you could split with regex of '-_\\.' and then start looking at the array elements. Likely more readable for others too. Perhaps I'm not completely understanding the requirements, though.

Comment: If you simply need to replace the characters before the last dot, the one of the extension, you can use the function myString.lastIndexOf('.'); to get the position of the dot and then act consequentally.

Comment: No, @DanielaMogini, the field I need to replace varies. It will not always be the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just wrote a short program and in both cases it works here it is:

```
public class StringTest 
{  

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        String str = "02-EST-WHATEVER-099-00.dwg";

        String newStr = str.replaceAll("([^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-)[^-_\\.]+(\\.[^-_\\.]+)", "$1$2");

        String regexRemoveRev = "([^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-[^-_\\.]+-)[^-_\\.]+(\\.[^-_\\.]+)";

        String newStr1 = str.replaceAll(regexRemoveRev, "$1$2");

        System.out.println("newStr: "+newStr);
        System.out.println("regexRemoveRev: "+regexRemoveRev);
        System.out.println("newStr: "+newStr1);

    }  
}
```

The out put from the above:

newStr: 02-EST-WHATEVER-099-.dwg
regexRemoveRev: ([^-*.]+-[^-*.]+-[^-*.]+-[^-*.]+-)[^-*.]+(.[^-*.]+)
newStr: 02-EST-WHATEVER-099-.dwg

I am not sure why is not working for you!! or is it something else you are asking and I got wrong

Comment: Yes, thanks. I realized I was putting together my `regexRemoveRev` variable incorrectly. Really appreciate everyone's help with this!